# Transfer javascript to jQuery for the carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert the JavaScript to jQuery for my carousel.

The code I had is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.indicators')[0].style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('.toggler-prev').style.display = 'none';
document.addEventListener('postchange', function(event){
  document.querySelectorAll('.indicators')[event.lastActiveIndex].style.color = 'white';
  document.querySelectorAll('.indicators')[event.activeIndex].style.color = 'red';
  var togglerPrev = document.querySelector('.toggler-prev');
  var togglerNext = document.querySelector('.toggler-next');
  if (event.activeIndex === 3) {
  togglerPrev.style.display = 'block';
  togglerNext.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (event.activeIndex === 0) {
  togglerNext.style.display = 'block';
  togglerPrev.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
  togglerNext.style.display = 'block';
  togglerPrev.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

Which I transferred to jQuery:

```
$('.indicators').css('color','#000');
$('.toggler-prev').css('display','none');
$(window).on('postchange', function(event){
  $('.indicators')[event.lastActiveIndex].css('color','#FFF');
  $('.indicators')[event.activeIndex].css('color','#000');
  var togglerPrev = $('.toggler-prev');
  var togglerNext = $('.toggler-next');
  if (event.activeIndex === 3) {
  togglerPrev.css('display','block');
  togglerNext.css('display','none');
  } else if (event.activeIndex === 0) {
  togglerNext.css('display','block');
  togglerPrev.css('display','none');
  } else {
  togglerNext.css('display','block');
  togglerPrev.css('display','block');
  }
});
```

But it isn't working as I expected for example togglers are not being hidden and color of indicators not being changed.

This is the working JS example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJYWQO

And my jQuery alternative: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJYWrq

Can anybody help me with editing my second codepen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention somewhere that you are using AngularJS and onsenUI ;)

Your problem is, that the jQuery event does not have the properties `activeIndex` and `lastActiveIndex`, but they can be found in `event.originalEvent`.

Also, like @stalin said in his answer, your indicators are no jQuery objects, therefore you can't call the `css`-function on them. Wrap this stuff in another jQuery constructor like `$()` or even better, use the `eq`-function which returns a jQuery wrapped object from an array.

Then, to optimize some of the readability, you might want to consider the `hide` and `show` function instead of changing the CSS property `display`.

---

All in all your code should look like this

```
$('.indicators').css('color', '#fff');
$('.indicators').eq(0).css('color', '#000'); // highlight the first indicator
$('.toggler-prev').hide();

$(window).on('postchange', function(event) {

    //store the indices for readability
    var activeIndex = event.originalEvent.activeIndex;
    var lastActiveIndex = event.originalEvent.lastActiveIndex;

    $('.indicators').eq(lastActiveIndex).css('color', '#FFF');
    $('.indicators').eq(activeIndex).css('color', '#000');

    var togglerPrev = $('.toggler-prev');
    var togglerNext = $('.toggler-next');

    if (activeIndex === carousel.getCarouselItemCount() - 1) {
        togglerPrev.show();
        togglerNext.hide();
    } else if (activeIndex === 0) {
        togglerNext.show();
        togglerPrev.hide();
    } else {
        togglerNext.show();
        togglerPrev.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your implementation

First the event is not trigered in `$(window)` is in the `$(document)`

Your variable like `lastActiveIndex` are not in the event object are in `event.originalEvent`

`$('.indicators')[event.lastActiveIndex]` return a dom object not a jquery object you need to wrap this result in a jquery object to use the `css()` function

After you fix all this your code will work

Sorry that don't have time for create a fiddle for you :)